# How can I add watch table in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, debugging

I had worked C++ in windows OS.
But it's my first time that I'm working C++ using Macbook.

Can I add watch tab while I debug it ?
So that I can check variables in multi watch tab in Xcode.
I want to monitor variables using in multi tabs !!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqMXN.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGdje.png)

Comment: You can certainly set a watchpoint in the Xcode debugger. I do not know what a watch tab is. If it's a vscode feature maybe you should use vscode.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I don't know, which word is using in English about the tab to monitor variables. But I guess it is watch tab.
When I use in Visual Studio, I can handle multi watch tabs. But in my MacBook and as using Xcode. There is only 1 watch tab T_T

Comment: Anyway I uploaded second attached image, is that tab named as watch tab right ?? Or how can I speak the word in English to mention the tab ?? And the important is I'd like to control multiple the tabs in Xcode !
Thank you :)